# Text box not works properly when I use typeahead attribute

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using `typeahead` in my angularjs project.

I have these values to be displayed in textbox with `typeahead` attribute:

```
  $scope.cities = [{id:1,address:'Berlin'},
                   {id:2,address:'Bonn'},
                   {id:3,address:'London'},
                   {id:4,address:'Miami'}];
```

And here is input text box with `typeahead` attribute:

```
<input type="text" 
ng-model="city" 
ng-model="initFoo(1)"  
uib-typeahead="city as city.address for city in cities | filter:$viewValue"
class="form-control"  
typeahead-show-hint="true" 
typeahead-min-length="0"/>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/21SFjwhCbn6DjcdXvRBd?p=preview).

When initial value is set up with `initFoo` I can't remove selected or type in the text box.

Any idea how can I set initial value and keep my text box selectable and printable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ng-init` instead of `ng-model` to initialize model

```
  <input type="text" 
  ng-init="city = initFoo(1)"
  ng-model="city"
  uib-typeahead="city as city.address for city in cities | filter:$viewValue"
  class="form-control" 
  typeahead-show-hint="true" 
  typeahead-min-length="0"/>`
```